# Wordpress login refresh issue, have tried everything but it doesn't want to load

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

So I was given this file and was asked to integrate PayPal using WooComerce. but I can't seem to access the wp dashboard. Here's what I've done

Created a database in phpmyadmin using XAMPP, stored the files in my htdocs, and then imported an SQL file to the database, the website page loads on my localhost, but when I type http://localhost/mysite/wp-login.php or even http://localhost/mysite/wp-admin, and I enter the correct credentials, the login page just refreshes.

I have tried

1. clearing cache and cookies
2. removing .htaccess files
3. renamed plugins folder

But none of them seemed to work, the page just kept refreshing. I've even tried opening it in incognito mode because I heard it may help but it didn't. Please let me know if there's anything I missed or if any further information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone faces this issue, You should access the database file and go to wp_options and change the url there to match your localhost. You can add an admin command in your theme functions.php file as well after doing that to add more users.